# Lync server client less audio video

Tags: html, silverlight, video, lync

Am I correct in understanding that you cannot so CLIENTLESS audio/video with a mixture of lync server, html5 and silver light from the browser?

This is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only* way to do client-less Lync in the browser is with UCWA. Right now,UCWA is only IM/P but voice/video is coming by the end of the year. Everything else (apart from Lync Web Access obv) requires the client to be on the machine.

*you could write a web proxy to a UCMA service you've written which would achieve the same thing,but this wouldn't be able to do voice/video either.